# Apache Chemistry fails when creating a folder with blank spaces

Tags: php, alfresco, apache-chemistry

I'm using [API_Alfresco](https://github.com/donbalon4/API_Alfresco) which is a library to connect to Alfresco via Apache Chemistry, but I'm getting the following error when I try to create a folder with blank spaces:

```
 Uncaught CmisRuntimeException in C:\xampp\htdocs\API_Alfresco\cmis_repository_wrapper.php:176 Stack trace: 
    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\API_Alfresco\cmis_repository_wrapper.php(207): CMISRepositoryWrapper->convertStatusCode(505, '') 
    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\API_Alfresco\cmis_service.php(791): CMISRepositoryWrapper->doGet('...') 
    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\API_Alfresco\APIAlfresco.php(98): CMISService->getObjectByPath('...', Array)
    #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpCMISalfresco.php(33): APIAlfresco->setFolderByPath('...') 
    #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\API_Alfresco
```

When I try to create a folder with no blank spaces it works fine. Here's my code:

```
<?php
    require 'APIAlfresco/APIAlfresco.php';
    include 'connectAlfresco.php';

    $parent_name = $_POST['parent']; //FAILS IF IT HAS BLANK SPACES
    $uploaded_file = basename($_FILES['att_file']['name']); //Uploaded
    $base_folder = "/path/to/site/folder/"

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['att_file']['tmp_name'], $uploaded_file)) {

            $conexion->setFolderByPath($base_folder); //Set base folder where files will be uploaded 

        /*Check if dir already exists and create it if it doesn't */
            if($conexion->existsFolder($parent_name)) echo "Parent".$parent_name." already exists";
            else $conexion->createFolder($parent_name);

      /*Move uploaded file into folder */
            $conexion->setFolderByPath($base_folder."/".$parent_name); //ERROR HERE IF $parent_name HAS BLANK SPACES
            $conexion->uploadFile($uploaded_file);

    }

    echo 'File infor:';
    print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

I took a look to the error trace and realized that **doRequest()** call inside **doGet()** (in **cmis_repository_wrapper.php**) is returning an error within the HTTP request (only fails when folders contain blank spaces). Since I haven't coded the library I can't seem to figure out what could be going wrong. Any clues? Could it be a bug?

Also made some debugging and realized that doRequest() is taking an URL such as:

***http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom/path?path=/Sites/mysite/documentLibrary/Folder WithBlankSpaces&filter=&includeAllowableActions=&includeACL=&includePolicyIds=&includeRelationships=&renditionFilter=***

And in this link I'm noticing two things that could be triggering the error:

**1)** "Folder WithBlankSpaces" folder is splitting the URL in two (most likely to be the actual issue)

**2)** Vars in the last part of the url are unset

I suspect that **1)** could be the real issue, since if I force that folder to have no blank spaces (calling `str_replace(' ', '', $parent_folder)`) then it'll work fine.

How could I get it to work with folders **with** blank spaces? Is there any way I can modify that URL so blank spaces don't divide it in two? Of course if user tries to create "My Folder", what he wants to see is a "My Folder" directory and not a "MyFolder" one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That behaviour is the correct one and what is done in most systems.
In fact, Windows is the only operating system that I used where it's so trivial to have spaces in file names.

Would replacing spaces with underscores be a solution to your problem ? That way, these files would still be compatible with non-Windows systems.

Comment: Well actually Apache Chemistry removes underscores automatically so folders (or files) like "my_folder" will be automatically converted to "myfolder". Dots are the only reasonable way I see to separate words but I feel it's still pretty much of a workaround.

Comment: You might replace them with "%20" in their string representation... However, if you want both clean representations in the system and spaces available, I doubt you can easily be satisfied without devleoping your own solution. As I said, spaces are banned in most naming systems since they are used as a separator in the commands.

Comment: I also tried "%20" but Apache Chemistry just removes the % symbol so I end up with a folder such as "My20Folder". Well, dots seem to be accepted so I'll use it as a workaround until I figure out something else to allow use of spaces.

Comment: Well I figured it out myself. Check my own answer to the question in a few minutes to see how I solved it.

Comment: I admit I'm quite curious, now

Comment: Just posted the answer! Check it out if you want to know how did I manage to solve it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself. 
The idea is forcing blank spaces to be "%20" before making the HTTP request, and then replacing "%20" with blank spaces again.

Basically `$conexion->setFolderByPath($parent_name)` makes an HTTP request (that's where the error was being triggered when `$parent_name` contained spaces).

So, before calling that method, `$parent_name` spaces need to be replaced by "%20" so HTTP requests will know that there's a "blank space" in the url expressed as %20.

Once the HTTP request is done (after calling setFolderByPath()), "%20" needs to be replaced back to blank spaces to then call the `$conexion->createFolder($parent_name);` so the folder is created with actual blank spaces and not "%20".

**EDIT**: I'm posting the fixed code to make it clear.

```
 <?php
        require 'APIAlfresco/APIAlfresco.php';
        include 'connectAlfresco.php';

        $parent_name = $_POST['parent'];
        $parent_name = str_replace(' ', '%20', $parent_name); //PREPARE IT FOR THE HTTP REQUEST
        $uploaded_file = basename($_FILES['att_file']['name']); //Uploaded file
        $base_folder = "/path/to/site/folder/";

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['att_file']['tmp_name'], $uploaded_file)) {

                $conexion->setFolderByPath($base_folder); //Set base folder where files will be uploaded 

            /*Check if dir already exists and create it if it doesn't */
                if($conexion->existsFolder($parent_name)){
                    echo "Parent".$parent_name." already exists";
                }else{
                    $parent_name = str_replace('%20', ' ', $parent_name); //CHANGE IT BACK TO BLANK SPACES
                    $conexion->createFolder($parent_name);
                }
          /*Move uploaded file into folder */
                $final_folder = $base_folder."/".$parent_name;
                $final_folder = str_replace('%20', ' ', $final_folder); //ANOTHER HTTP REQUEST IS NEEDED

                $conexion->setFolderByPath($finalFolder); //ERROR HERE IF $parent_name HAS BLANK SPACES
                $conexion->uploadFile($uploaded_file);

        }

        echo 'File infor:';
        print_r($_FILES);
    ?>
```

**EDIT AFTER SOME DAYS:** 
Just in case anybody is interested, this is no longer needed to do in programmer's PHP code. I cloned the library, fixed this issue, pushed it to local branch and started a pull request. Now special characters as well as blank spaces are handled within the library. You can simply use `$conexion->setFolderByPath($parent_name)` and `$parent_name` can contain all sorts of special characters and spaces, and programmers don't need to take care of it.

Comment: Yep, however I can only accept my answer in two days ;)

Comment: This sounds like a bug in your CMIS library - it should be handling that stuff for you

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes, you're right, I digged into the CMIS library and it was actually a bug. When creating a folder it doesn't remove special chars and replace blank spaces with "%20" (basically it does not call extractSpecialChars() method). I'll modify the library and make a pull request once I get it to work.

Comment: Just in case anybody is interested, this is no longer needed to do in programmer's PHP code. I cloned the library, fixed this issue, pushed it and started a pull request. Now special characters as well as blank spaces are handled within the library.